# Combine Mono with Flux

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactor

I want to create a service that combines results from two reactive sources.
One is producing Mono and another one is producing Flux. For merging I need the same value of mono for every flux emitted.

For now I have something like this

```
Flux.zip(
   service1.getConfig(), //produces flux
   service2.getContext() //produces mono
           .cache().repeat()
)
```

This gives me what I need,

- service2 is called only once
- context is provided for every configuration
- resulting flux has as many elements as configurations

But I have noticed that repeat() is emitting a massive amount of elements after context is cached. Is this a problem?

Is there something I can do to limit number of repeats to the number of received configurations, yet still do both request simultaneously?
Or this is not an issue and I Can safely ignore those extra emitted elements?

I tried to use `combineLatest` but depending on timing I some elements fo configuration can get lost and not processed.

**EDIT**

Looking at the suggestions from @Ricard Kollcaku I have created sample test that shows why this is not what I'm looking for.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

public class SampleTest
{
    Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SampleTest.class);
    AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong(0);

    Flux<String> getFlux()
    {
        return Flux.fromStream(() -> {
            LOG.info("flux started");
            sleep(1000);
            return Stream.of("a", "b", "c");
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel());
    }

    Mono<String> getMono()
    {
        return Mono.defer(() -> {
            counter.incrementAndGet();
            LOG.info("mono started");
            sleep(1000);
            return Mono.just("mono");
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel());
    }

    private void sleep(final long milis)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(milis);
        }
        catch (final InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test
    void test0()
    {
        final Flux<String> result = Flux.zip(
                getFlux(),
                getMono().cache().repeat()
                         .doOnNext(n -> LOG.warn("signal on mono", n)),
                (s1, s2) -> s1 + " " + s2
        );

        assertResults(result);
    }

    @Test
    void test1()
    {
        final Flux<String> result =
                getFlux().flatMap(s -> Mono.zip(Mono.just(s), getMono(),
                        (s1, s2) -> s1 + " " + s2));
        assertResults(result);
    }

    @Test
    void test2()
    {
        final Flux<String> result = getFlux().flatMap(s -> getMono().map((s1 -> s + " " + s1)));
        assertResults(result);
    }

    void assertResults(final Flux<String> result)
    {
        final Flux<String> flux = result;

        StepVerifier.create(flux)
                    .expectNext("a mono")
                    .expectNext("b mono")
                    .expectNext("c mono")
                    .verifyComplete();

        Assertions.assertEquals(1L, counter.get());
    }
```

Looking at the test results for test1 and test2

```
2020-01-20 12:55:22.542 INFO  [] [] [     parallel-3]  SampleTest  : flux started  
2020-01-20 12:55:24.547 INFO  [] [] [     parallel-4]  SampleTest  : mono started  
2020-01-20 12:55:24.547 INFO  [] [] [     parallel-5]  SampleTest  : mono started  
2020-01-20 12:55:24.548 INFO  [] [] [     parallel-6]  SampleTest  : mono started  

expected: <1> but was: <3>
```

I need to reject your proposal. In both cases getMono is 
- invoked as many times as items in flux
- invoked after first element of flux arrives
And those are interactions that I want to avoid. My services are making http requests under the hood and they may be time consuming.

My current solution does not have this problem, but if I add logger to my zip I will get this

```
2020-01-20 12:55:20.505 INFO  [] [] [     parallel-1]  SampleTest  : flux started  
2020-01-20 12:55:20.508 INFO  [] [] [     parallel-2]  SampleTest  : mono started  
2020-01-20 12:55:21.523 WARN  [] [] [     parallel-2]  SampleTest  : signal on mono  
2020-01-20 12:55:21.528 WARN  [] [] [     parallel-2]  SampleTest  : signal on mono  
2020-01-20 12:55:21.529 WARN  [] [] [     parallel-2]  SampleTest  : signal on mono  
2020-01-20 12:55:21.529 WARN  [] [] [     parallel-2]  SampleTest  : signal on mono  
2020-01-20 12:55:21.529 WARN  [] [] [     parallel-2]  SampleTest  : signal on mono  
2020-01-20 12:55:21.529 WARN  [] [] [     parallel-2]  SampleTest  : signal on mono  
2020-01-20 12:55:21.530 WARN  [] [] [     parallel-2]  SampleTest  : signal on mono  
2020-01-20 12:55:21.530 WARN  [] [] [     parallel-2]  SampleTest  : signal on mono  
2020-01-20 12:55:21.530 WARN  [] [] [     parallel-2]  SampleTest  : signal on mono  
2020-01-20 12:55:21.530 WARN  [] [] [     parallel-2]  SampleTest  : signal on mono  
2020-01-20 12:55:21.531 WARN  [] [] [     parallel-2]  SampleTest  : signal on mono  
2020-01-20 12:55:21.531 WARN  [] [] [     parallel-2]  SampleTest  : signal on mono  
2020-01-20 12:55:21.531 WARN  [] [] [     parallel-2]  SampleTest  : signal on mono  
2020-01-20 12:55:21.531 WARN  [] [] [     parallel-2]  SampleTest  : signal on mono  
2020-01-20 12:55:21.531 WARN  [] [] [     parallel-2]  SampleTest  : signal on mono  
2020-01-20 12:55:21.532 WARN  [] [] [     parallel-2]  SampleTest  : signal on mono  
2020-01-20 12:55:21.532 WARN  [] [] [     parallel-2]  SampleTest  : signal on mono  
2020-01-20 12:55:21.532 WARN  [] [] [     parallel-2]  SampleTest  : signal on mono  
2020-01-20 12:55:21.532 WARN  [] [] [     parallel-2]  SampleTest  : signal on mono  
2020-01-20 12:55:21.533 WARN  [] [] [     parallel-2]  SampleTest  : signal on mono  
2020-01-20 12:55:21.533 WARN  [] [] [     parallel-2]  SampleTest  : signal on mono  
2020-01-20 12:55:21.533 WARN  [] [] [     parallel-2]  SampleTest  : signal on mono  
2020-01-20 12:55:21.533 WARN  [] [] [     parallel-2]  SampleTest  : signal on mono  
2020-01-20 12:55:21.533 WARN  [] [] [     parallel-2]  SampleTest  : signal on mono  
2020-01-20 12:55:21.533 WARN  [] [] [     parallel-2]  SampleTest  : signal on mono  
2020-01-20 12:55:21.533 WARN  [] [] [     parallel-2]  SampleTest  : signal on mono  
2020-01-20 12:55:21.534 WARN  [] [] [     parallel-2]  SampleTest  : signal on mono  
2020-01-20 12:55:21.534 WARN  [] [] [     parallel-2]  SampleTest  : signal on mono  
2020-01-20 12:55:21.534 WARN  [] [] [     parallel-2]  SampleTest  : signal on mono  
2020-01-20 12:55:21.534 WARN  [] [] [     parallel-2]  SampleTest  : signal on mono  
2020-01-20 12:55:21.534 WARN  [] [] [     parallel-2]  SampleTest  : signal on mono  
2020-01-20 12:55:21.535 WARN  [] [] [     parallel-2]  SampleTest  : signal on mono
```

As you can see there is a lot of elements emitted by combining `cache().repeat()` together and I want to know if this is an issue and if yes then how to avoid it (but keep single invocation of mono and parallel invocation).

Comment: Why not flat mapping through Mono, e.g. something like this `Mono.just(1).flux().flatMap(v1 -> Flux.just(2, 3).map(v2 -> v1 + v2));`

Comment: Your problem is this one ? stream 1 emitting 1,2,3,4 stream 2 emitting only a. And your able to process only 1,a when you want to process 1,a - 2,a - 3,a - 4,a ?

Comment: @efan - that would work but (from my understanding of react) I will be making request to `Flux.just(2, 3)` only when `Mono` emits a value. And I would like to start both request at the same time and combine results when they are available.

@RicardKollcaku - not exactly. I'm able to process `1,a 2,a 3,a ...` but in the way to achieve it i'm producing absurd amount of `a` due to how `cache().repeat()` works.

Comment: @RobertOzga with your edit i explain better why you dont wont mono to be created many times. I have edited the answer so Mono will be created just 1 time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are trying to achieve could be done with `Flux.join`

Here is some example code:

```
Flux<Integer> flux = Flux.concat(Mono.just(1).delayElement(Duration.ofMillis(100)),
        Mono.just(2).delayElement(Duration.ofMillis(500))).log();

Mono<String> mono = Mono.just("a").delayElement(Duration.ofMillis(50)).log();

List<String> list = flux.join(mono, (v1) -> Flux.never(), (v2) -> Flux.never(), (x, y) -> {
    return x + y;
}).collectList().block();

System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Libraries like Project Reactor and RxJava try to provide as much combinations of their capabilities as possible, but do not provide access to the instruments of combining capabilities. And as a result, there are always corner cases which are not covered.

My own DF4J, as far as I know, is the only asynchronous library which provides the means to combine capabilities. For example, this is how user can zip Flux and Mono: (of course, this class is not part of DF4J itself):

```
import org.df4j.core.dataflow.Actor;
import org.df4j.core.port.InpFlow;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

abstract class ZipActor<T1, T2> extends Actor {
    InpFlow<T1> inpFlow = new InpFlow<>(this);
    InpFlow<T2> inpScalar = new InpFlow<>(this);

    ZipActor(Flux<T1> flux, Mono<T2> mono) {
        flux.subscribe(inpFlow);
        mono.subscribe(inpScalar);
    }

    @Override
    protected void runAction() throws Throwable {
        if (inpFlow.isCompleted()) {
            stop();
            return;
        }
        T1 element1 = inpFlow.removeAndRequest();
        T2 element2 = inpScalar.current();
        runAction(element1, element2);
    }

    protected abstract void runAction(T1 element1, T2 element2);
}
```

and this is how it can be used:

```
@Test
public void ZipActorTest() {
    Flux<Integer> flux = Flux.just(1,2,3);
    Mono<Integer> mono = Mono.just(5);
    ZipActor<Integer, Integer> actor = new ZipActor<Integer, Integer>(flux, mono){
        @Override
        protected void runAction(Integer element1, Integer element2) {
            System.out.println("got:"+element1+" and:"+element2);
        }
    };
    actor.start();
    actor.join();
}
```

The console output is as follows:

```
got:1 and:5
got:2 and:5
got:3 and:5
```

Comment: Thanks for he suggestion this would probably solve my problem. Unfortunately I would need to struggle with my company "corporate policy" just to be able to include your library in our project (e.g. issues of support / patches etc) :(

Also including external library to solve one issue may not be the best approach if there are other (not as good but still) viable solutions.

Nevertheless thanks for posting, I will keep your lib in mind for future use cases :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where you're coming from here - reactor does provide capabilities to combine streams through the Flux.zip etc. methods. For the sake of transparency, you should also note you're the author of DF4J.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with just a simple change

```
    getFlux()
    .flatMap(s -> Mono.zip(Mono.just(s),getMono(), (s1, s2) -> s1+" "+s2))
    .subscribe(System.out::println);

Flux<String> getFlux(){
    return Flux.just("a","b","c");
}
Mono<String> getMono(){
    return  Mono.just("mono");
}
```

if you want to use zip but you can achieve same results using flatmap

```
      getFlux()
            .flatMap(s -> getMono()
                    .map((s1 -> s + " " + s1)))
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
}

Flux<String> getFlux() {
    return Flux.just("a", "b", "c");
}

Mono<String> getMono() {
    return Mono.just("mono");
}
```

in both result is:
a mono
b mono
c mono

EDIT
Ok now i understand it better. Can you try this solution.

```
   getMono().
            flatMapMany(s -> getFlux().map(s1 -> s1 + " " + s))
            .subscribe(System.out::println);


Flux<String> getFlux() {
    return Flux.defer(() -> {
        System.out.println("init flux");
        return Flux.just("a", "b", "c");
    });
}

Mono<String> getMono() {
    return Mono.defer(() -> {
        System.out.println("init Mono");
        return Mono.just("sss");
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response but this will not work.
I have edited my question to better explain my expectations and why your proposal does not suite my needs.

Comment: This works better - single call to mono. But the code is still waiting for mono to emit result before invoking flux request. I would prefer to start both at the same time (zip logic with cancelation of other requests if one fails is also nice here) but I looks like this is not possible