# Conditionally combine Mono with Flux

Tags: java, project-reactor

I need to combine the results from two reactive Publishers - Mono and Flux. I tried to do it with `zip` and `join` functions, but I was not able to fulfil two specific conditions:

1. result should contain as many element as Flux emits, but corresponding Mono source should be called only once (this condition alone can be implemented with `join`)
2. when Flux is empty, then chain should complete without waiting for Mono element

The solution for the first condition is presented in the [Combine Mono with Flux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59787201/combine-mono-with-flux) entry (pasted below). But I was not able to achieve second condition without blocking the chain - and that I would like to avoid.

```
Flux<Integer> flux = Flux.concat(Mono.just(1).delayElement(Duration.ofMillis(100)),
        Mono.just(2).delayElement(Duration.ofMillis(500))).log();

Mono<String> mono = Mono.just("a").delayElement(Duration.ofMillis(50)).log();

List<String> list = flux.join(mono, (v1) -> Flux.never(), (v2) -> Flux.never(), (x, y) -> {
    return x + y;
}).collectList().block();

System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say `When flux is empty`? Provide an example of how you get this empty Flux.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cancel the entire operation if Flux is empty you could do the below

```
Flux<Integer> flux = Flux.concat(Mono.just(1).delayElement(Duration.ofMillis(100)),
            Mono.just(2).delayElement(Duration.ofMillis(500))).log();

//Uncomment below and comment out above statement for empty flux

//Flux<Integer> flux = Flux.empty();

Mono<String> mono = Mono.just("a").delayElement(Duration.ofMillis(5000)).log();

//Throw exception if flux is empty
flux = flux.switchIfEmpty(Flux.error(IllegalStateException::new));

List<String> list = flux
        .join(mono, s -> Flux.never() , s -> Flux.never(), (x, y) -> x + y)
        //Catch exception and return nothing
        .onErrorResume(s -> Flux.empty())
        .collectList().block();

    System.out.println(list);
```

You could do something like the following if you want Mono to complete but don't want join to hang

```
DirectProcessor<Integer> processor = DirectProcessor.create();
//Could omit sink, and use processor::onComplete in place of sink::complete
//But typically recommended as provides better thread safety
FluxSink<Integer> sink = processor.serialize().sink();

Flux<Integer> flux = Flux.concat(Mono.just(1).delayElement(Duration.ofMillis(100)),
    Mono.just(2).delayElement(Duration.ofMillis(500))).log();

//Uncomment below and comment out above statement for empty flux

//Flux<Integer> flux = Flux.empty();

Mono<String> mono = Mono.just("a").delayElement(Duration.ofMillis(5000)).log();

List<String> list = flux
     .doOnComplete(sink::complete)
     .join(mono, s -> processor , s -> processor, (x, y) -> x + y).collectList().block();

System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I have never used these elements directly (FluxSink, DirectProcessor). However it did not seem to help. I added `log()` at the end of mono definition and the mono is called even when I use (uncomment) empty flux item:

`2020-05-12 11:32:53.560 INFO  [] [] [           main]  reactor.Mono.DelayElement.1              : onSubscribe([Fuseable] MonoDelayElement.DelayElementSubscriber) `,  
`2020-05-12 11:32:53.569 INFO  [] [] [           main]  reactor.Mono.DelayElement.1              : request(unbounded) `

Comment: @ŁukaszSocha Oh though you just didn't want it to hang waiting for elements that would never come. See edit